# Config option for git-tfs checkin to use --no-merge by default

Tags: git-tfs

Is there an option to add something to git-tfs config, so the `checkin` (and `checkintool`) command uses `--no-merge` flag by default.

I want to use

```
git tfs checkin
```

instead of

```
git tfs checkin --no-merge
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can, but did you consider making an alias and use that for checking in?

`git config --global alias.tc "tfs checkin --no-merge"`

`git tc`